# How to download using Conkeror when the download link is hidden behind a Rt Click menu

Tags: conkeror

As an example consider emacswiki and the need to download .el files.
This page http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/help-fns%2b.el has a green download button which the user Rt Clicks on in Firefox to get a "Save Link As" function.  How to do something similar in Conkeror?  It would be nice to have a both keyboard and mouse solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find major Conkeror keys on [this](http://conkeror.org/QuickStart) page.

In your case try to use **s** key and "choose" the link in Conkeror.